# Distinct in Laravel 5 not working properly

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, distinct

I want the distinct names from my database table.The table contains column id and name.

I have tried
 `$diff=Crud::distinct('name')->get();` 
`$diff=Crud::distinct()->get();` 
Both of them not worked.They are returning the result with duplicates.Here Crud is my eloquent model.

But when i use

```
$cnt=Crud::distinct()->count('name'); //returns the correct count
```

and

```
$u=Crud::all();
$diff=$u->unique('name'); //returns the distinct names
```

Why duplicate values are returned while i'm using the distinct? I want distinct names by using distinct.
**Thanks**.

Comment: Crud is the name of your Model?

Comment: yes! Crud is the name of my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distinct()` doesn't accept arguments. Use one of these options:

```php
$diff = Crud::distinct()->pluck('name');

$diff = Crud::distinct()->get(['name']);

$diff = Crud::distinct()->select('name')->get();
```

Comment: Correct. `distinct()` is only a flag in the query builder. You still need to tell the database what to distinct on. That's why `->count('name');` worked. While `DB::all()->unique()` is a collection method.